# .responsetext does not get the entire code

Tags: html, vba

On following website, i am trying to fetch the value(970.15 today) using MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP and .responsetext.
I have done it on another site and found the info in the text.
On that site though, .responsetext does not this value anywhere, but when i do inspect element in my browser, i do see it !
I discovered that function to read information on sites only last week, so still learning ! If anyone can help me, that would be great !

https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/indices/equity/sp-euro-50-equal-weight-50-point-decrement-index/#overview

Since it did not work, i put .responsetext value in a cell and copy/pasted it in notepad but did not find 970 is the file.
Note that to put the text in a cell, i had to get rid of the first 50 characters ... i did not understand this either !

Thanks !
G

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Note that just because a technique you use works on one website that does not mean it will work everywhere.

Comment: Having said that... When you debug, what *is* in the response?  How does it differ from what's in the response *for that exact request* in your web browser?  It's entirely possible that any given web page dynamically modifies its content after the page has loaded.  You need to specifically reverse-engineer where that value is coming from.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Debug.print will only show about 200 lines I think